# Send Email From Database

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to send an email from a sever to a couple of recipients.

I do query my database using:

```
SELECT Email from payrollchecksystem
```

And than use the following to send the email

```
USE msdb
GO
EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='SQL Server Alerts System',
@recipients = I DONT KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE
@subject='Test message',
@body='This is the body of the test message.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.'
```

My problem is that I dont know what to put for @recipients when trying to send all the emails I got from the payrollchecksystem table?

Answer (score 5):

To separate your e-mails into a semi-colon delimited string, use `COALESCE`:

```
DECLARE @EmailList varchar(MAX)

SELECT  @EmailList = COALESCE(@EmailList + ';', '') + Email
FROM    payrollchecksystem
WHERE   Email IS NOT NULL

SELECT  @EmailList
```

Then you can use @EmailList like so:

```
USE msdb
GO
EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='SQL Server Alerts System',
     @recipients = @EmailList,
     @subject='Test message',
     @body='This is the body of the test message. Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.'
```

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx

> @recipients
>   Is a semicolon-delimited list of
>   e-mail addresses to send the message
>   to

Comment: But what if Im trying to send an email to 100 recipients. I did create a .csv file with the list of recipients . What should I put in that case for the @recipients?

Comment: You should put the 100 email addresses, separated by semicolons, like the documentation says